# Has anyone ever used the Mega Bus?

Tags: usa, budget, buses, price

I just looked at a Mega Bus trip from anonymous, Tennessee, to New York City for 81 dollars. Is it dangerous?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands, if not into millions of people have probably used a megabus in one of the countries they operate in. What's your specific question?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: How would it be dangerous? More dangerous than flying? Than driving yourself? Than other bus operators? Than standing in a field during a lightning storm?

Comment: Are you allowed to carry weapons on the bus?

Comment: @GettingNifty Are you referring to the fact that Greyhound is sometimes considered used by dangerous population? I do not think there is any reputation for Megabus. For road dangerosity, you can [read about the incidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabus_%28North_America%29#Incidents_and_accidents)

Comment: US bus (coach) operators do not use metal detectors (after all, in some cases they pick up at roadside like a city bus), so your fellow passengers indeed may have weapons. But, then, they might also have weapons in any random restaurant you visit. If this concerns you (and I am in no way justifying the ease of buying guns in Tennessee!), this entire trip is not for you regardless of means of transport.

Comment: Welcome to the United States. Everything you've heard in the mass media about this being the wild west with shootouts everywhere all the time, ranges from overblown to entirely false.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're only interested in the [US version of Megabus](http://us.megabus.com/), given the route mentioned, then their [homepage lists](http://us.megabus.com/) that they've transported over 40 million passengers so far! Given that, the answer to your main question is:

**Yes**

Large numbers of people have used Megabus!

In terms of your edit asking if it's dangerous, the answer is "not really". You can find out all about Megabus's [safety and training on their website](http://us.megabus.com/safetyandtraining.aspx), which should help reassure you that they're a reliable and reputable coach operator. Given that, depending on what sort of car you'd otherwise drive in, it's potentially safer than driving yourself!